# Are all sins forgivable?

Tags: sin

I am in desperate need of advising.
Recently, I have been connecting more with my religion and it’s never felt better. But something has come to my attention that is causing me a serious amount of distress. Astrology is something that is becoming so popular all over the world. Some believe it while others just look it up for fun. I never had a belief in it but like others, I thought it was fun but wasn’t really all about it as others were.
One time, I saw the criticizing of Astrology from an Islamic perspective a while ago, and by thought that surely it doesn’t mean anything if you don’t actually take it seriously, right? Then a long time later, I found out that Astrology is Shirk by one article, and I was completely taken aback and treaded such areas carefully. I thought that surely there was an misunderstanding, because I don’t think I knew what that word actually meant—I thought it meant the active belief of the existence of more than one God, which I have obviously never believed.
Still, I remained cautious. Then, after a short while, many girls in my class were having a discussion about their zodiac signs. Many of them had a similar one so they had this long and elaborate discussion. I was very weary, but utterly lost because these girls were not only Muslim, but they were born and raised in a Muslim country. They only felt the need to clarify that they didn’t believe in Palm-reading and had only done it once for fun. This is also common.
I was so confused at this point and thought to myself, if these very much practicing Muslim girls are saying these things, then surely I am mistaken, and it was not Shirk. I laughed when they made jokes in the conversation and they asked me for mine but I wasn’t really contributing much.
Still, I remained cautious of the topic and refused to approach it. My brother also told me it was Shirk. After a while, I heard of many other examples of Shirk I didn’t know about, like putting your wedding ring on your ring finger.
I am now realizing how many incidents there have been that could’ve been Shirk in my life, which I never thought to be Shrik, especially because I was raised in a western country.
I am absolutely terrified at the moment.
I have never believed that there was another god than Allah and inshallah never will. But I cannot get this out of my brain. I can also not get out of my brain how many people believe this is unforgivable.
I know we should never limit the mercy of Allah, but do we know that this can be forgiven?

Comment: Assalam walakium Shirk can be forgiven with a SINCERE repentance but if you die in the state of shirk and you never repented from it Allah cannot forgive you but he can forgive any other sin when you die IF he pleases I hope this answers your question and may Allah forgive your sins repent now before it’s too late my brother death can happen at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Palm-reading, horoscopes and predicting the (ghayb) unseen in any way, shape or form is shirk. As you are setting partners with Allah. Even though [only Allah knows the unseen!](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/101968)

As for doing it for fun, then your [prayers would be rendered invalid for forty days and it's minor shirk. And if you believe in what they say.. That is setting up partners (shirk). Which constitutes to major shirk](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/112069) that takes someone outside the fold of Islam

[Here is a comprehensive article that explains Shirk](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/34817)

Allah can forgive all sins,

> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves (by sinning), do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."

but with [conditions](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/46683/acceptance-of-repentance)... Which are to

1. Give up the sin immediately.
2. Regret having done it.
3. Resolve never to go back to it.

If you believed in what they said, I invite you to take the shahadah again,
أَشْهَدُ أَنْ لَا إِلَهَ إِلَّا اللَّهُ وَأَشْهَدُ أَنَّ مُحَمَّدًارَسُولُ الله

I recommend some books to further research shirk

- [Prohibitions that are taken too lightly](https://islamqa.info/en/books/27/prohibitions-that-are-taken-too-lightly)
- [Kitab at-Tawheed](https://abdurrahmanorg.files.wordpress.com/2019/06/kt-english.pdf)

The latter may get confusing so here is an explanation by ibn 'uthaymeen

- [1st volume](https://darpdfs.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Commentary-on-Kitab-At-Tawheed-Vol.-1-Sh.-Al-Uthaymeen-compressed.pdf)
- [2nd volume](https://darpdfs.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Commentary-on-Kitab-At-Tawheed-Vol.-2-Sh.-Al-Uthaymeen-compressed.pdf)

*I have used Saheeh international*

Answer (score 0):

Ask for forgiveness to allah, he will forgive you, Allah says in Quran :

> tell them (o prophet)," my servants who have committed excesses against
> themselves (committed sins) do not lose hope in Allah's mercy, surely
> Allah forgives all sins(with repentance). Allah is the most forgiving
> most merciful.(39:53)

Don't think about your past, let bygones be bygones, start a new beginning with trust in Allah, he is with you